# apply Git patch from remote commit in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a gerrit link with the changeId / commit Id

I want to apply the diff from this to my local workspace

```
git diff patch.txt > path_to_file/patch.txt
```

does not give required results.

Answer (score 1):

Any commit pushed to Gerrit has its own branch, named as refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1. Gerrit provides several ssh and repo commands like checkout, cherry-pick, format patch and etc in the dropdown menu of Download at the top-right of the page. You could just copy and paste them to use.

`git fetch ssh://xxx:29418/yyy.git refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1 && git format-patch -1 --stdout FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: If the goal is to apply changes from a given changeset, _and_ I have cloned the repository, then I would use `git cherry-pick`

Comment: Agree. Moreover, you could try `ssh -p 29418 username@gerrithost gerrit query commit:commitID --current-patch-set | grep ref | awk '{print $2}'` to get the exact refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1, which you could easily fetch and do subsequent actions.